# Find the relative position of a specific number in an increasing vector

Tags: r

I have a simple question. I have a numeric vector with increasing order.

e.g.

```
[1] 13.5 13.9 14.2 14.5 14.8 15.2 16.0 16.9 17.4 17.8 18.3 18.7 19.4
```

and I want to find the relative position of a specific number between these vectors.

e.g.

```
     f(13) 
           ' < 13.5 '
     f(15.0)
           ' 14.8 <=  < 15.2
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html).

Comment: @PeongGangPark `findInterval` only gives you interval numbers. If you want interval labels, `cut` is preferable. The labels can be customized or by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cut()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html):

```r
vec <- c(13.5, 13.9, 14.2, 14.5, 14.8, 15.2, 16.0, 16.9, 17.4, 17.8, 18.3, 18.7, 19.4)

cut(13, c(-Inf, vec, Inf))
# [1] (-Inf,13.5]

cut(15, c(-Inf, vec, Inf))
# [1] (14.8,15.2]
```